# Is there a way to merge user profiles on xbox360?

Tags: xbox-360

When I first got my 360 I didn't get live, so I made a user profile, that we'll call profile A.  On this profile I beat Gears of War 1, and received many achievements and such.  Later on I got Xbox live, and made a different account, because you have to, that we'll call profile B, on this account I've been playing Gears 2 and 3.

So I was wondering If there is anyway to combine these two accounts so my achievements and gamer score for profiles A could be incorporated into profile B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the only way you can do it is if you have one profile that is offline and one that has a registered gamer card on Xbox.com (this second account can't be on Xbox live). I found this link on Xbox.com which gives you step by step instructions on how to combine the two profiles:

http://mktplassets.xbox.com/NR/exeres/7239CD88-DE65-408D-AE16-0FC0F8CB4230.htm

If your other profile is on Live then unfortunately, at this time, there is no way of merging the two profiles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I looked at the link and it seams like it would only work if you're joining xbox live for the first time, not if you already have an online and offline profile.