# How do you join two Xbox Live accounts?

Tags: xbox-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to merge user profiles on xbox360?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32709/is-there-a-way-to-merge-user-profiles-on-xbox360)

I made an Games for Windows Live account a few years ago using my Gmail address. Some time ago I also started playing on my friend's Xbox and subsequently made a new account with my Hotmail address (having forgot about my first account). I've recently started gaming on the PC again and also using Games for Windows Live.

You see, now I have two accounts which I would like to join, because both accounts have achievements and other such stuff, I'd like to have it all under one account.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I'm interested in any answers you get as I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to accomplish this. Microsoft do not provide any function to merge gamertags.

Comment: After looking into it some more, it does seem that this is impossible. Well, too bad :(